# At what point are hard drive bad sectors actually bad?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, bad-sectors

I'm kind of freaking out here, so I'm sorry if this question may be panicked.

So, today, when I started my system up, I took a look at one of the drives in my Raid 0 setup. It showed 7 bad sectors. Alright. That's fair. Several hours later, I took another look. 10 bad sectors!

Now, I've been doing a LOT of copying and downloading onto that drive (Maybe, around 100GB transfers), so is it possible that those sectors were there, but just not recorded as being bad? None of the bad sectors have been irrecoverable yet, but at what point should I start considering options for replacement?

Even a little bit of help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You'd want to back up as soon as you start getting bad sectors. Hard drives are easily replacable, data is less so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAID 0 is striping and if you have a back up then don't panic.  The bigger issue is the rate of increase.  I would definitely start planning to replace the drive.  However, to detect how bad the drive is really I would use mhdd or spinrite.  Spinrite may not like drives over 1tb and mhdd is free anyway.  However spinrite is the better tool.